# Replace values in specific columns where conditions are met for rows from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes representing two monthly datasets. I am trying to roll back the values in `df1` (current month) with the values in `df2` (previous month) if the value in `fb` is `Y`. The actual dataset is thousands of records long and there are 30 or so columns that need to be reset/rolled back. The double for loops in the code below return null values in `df1`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'loan_num': [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
    'bal': [100000, 100000, 150000, 225000, 350000, 500000],
    'rate': [2.25, 3.75, 4.00, 4.25, 6.125, 2.50],
    'sfee': [0.25, 0.19, 0.25, 0.44, 0.25, 0.19],
    'fb': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'loan_num': [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
    'bal': [125000, 150000, 200000, 275000, 355000, 550000],
    'rate': [2.25, 3.75, 4.00, 4.25, 6.125, 2.50],
    'sfee': [0.30, 0.22, 0.27, 0.75, 0.25, 0.55],
    'fb': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y']
})

fb_loans = df1.loc[df1['fb'] == 'Y', 'loan_num'].tolist()
cols_to_reset = ['bal', 'sfee']

for loan in fb_loans:
    for col in cols_to_reset:
        df1.loc[df1['loan_num'] == loan, col] = df2.loc[df2['loan_num'] == loan, col]
```

If I set the right side of the assignment statement to an fixed value, the output is correct. I've also tried the following:

```
for loan in fb_loans:
     df1.loc[df1['loan_num'] == loan, 'bal'] = df2.loc[df2['loan_num'] == loan, 'bal']
     df1.loc[df1['loan_num'] == loan, 'sfee'] = df2.loc[df2['loan_num'] == loan, 'sfee']
```

```
for loan in fb_loans:
    for col in cols_to_reset:
        new_value = df2.loc[df2['loan_num'] == loan, col]
        df1.loc[df1['loan_num'] == loan, col] = new_value
```

Both methods produced null values for the columns of interest in `df1`.

My expected output for `df1` is:

```
+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----+
| loan_num | bal      | rate    | sfee    | fb  |
+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----+
| 100      | 125000   | 2.25    | 0.30    | Y   |
| 101      | 100000   | 3.75    | 0.19    | N   |
| 102      | 150000   | 4.00    | 0.25    | N   |
| 103      | 275000   | 4.25    | 0.75    | Y   |
| 104      | 350000   | 6.125   | 0.25    | N   |
| 105      | 550000   | 2.50    | 0.55    | Y   |
+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'loan_num': [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
    'bal': [100000, 100000, 150000, 225000, 350000, 500000],
    'rate': [2.25, 3.75, 4.00, 4.25, 6.125, 2.50],
    'sfee': [0.25, 0.19, 0.25, 0.44, 0.25, 0.19],
    'fb': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'loan_num': [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105],
    'bal': [125000, 150000, 200000, 275000, 355000, 550000],
    'rate': [2.25, 3.75, 4.00, 4.25, 6.125, 2.50],
    'sfee': [0.30, 0.22, 0.27, 0.75, 0.25, 0.55],
    'fb': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y']
})
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on='loan_num', how = 'right', suffixes=('', '_df2'))
new_df['bal'] = np.where(new_df['fb']=='Y', new_df['bal_df2'], new_df['bal'])
new_df['rate'] = np.where(new_df['fb']=='Y', new_df['rate_df2'], new_df['rate'])
new_df['sfee'] = np.where(new_df['fb']=='Y', new_df['sfee_df2'], new_df['sfee'])
new_df = new_df.iloc[:, [not o.endswith('_df2') for o in new_df.columns]]
new_df
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['loan_num'], how='left')
```

which gives you (the `_y` columns coming from `df2`):

```
   loan_num   bal_x  rate_x  sfee_x fb_x   bal_y  rate_y  sfee_y fb_y
0       100  100000   2.250    0.25    Y  125000   2.250    0.30    Y
1       101  100000   3.750    0.19    N  150000   3.750    0.22    N
2       102  150000   4.000    0.25    N  200000   4.000    0.27    N
3       103  225000   4.250    0.44    Y  275000   4.250    0.75    Y
4       104  350000   6.125    0.25    N  355000   6.125    0.25    N
5       105  500000   2.500    0.19    Y  550000   2.500    0.55    Y
```

Since you are merging on one key column, you can use map:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('loan_num')
df1['bal'] = df1['loan_num'].map(df2['bal'])
df1['sfee'] = df1['loan_num'].map(df2['sfee'])
```